# I have a question about algebra. This question is based off of a random game I played.

Tags: probability

An action has a base cost of 200 and has a 20% chance to succeed. With every 10 dollars added, the said action's success rate increases by 1% capping at 75%. Which percent would be the most efficient if you have ~2500 dollars.

I'm assuming it makes no difference although I could be wrong. My equation follows:

y=((x/100)^-1)*10x which simplifies to y=1000

X is the percent. i.e.(10% would be x=10)X can only be between 20 and 75 inclusive.

Y is the amount of money theoretically required to get a 100% chance.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what you're trying to optimize, I suspect.  Are you trying to optimize for maximum probability of success with the $\$2500$, or are you trying to optimize for expected cost per success, or something else? ¶ Note that the base cost is at the same rate as the bonus points, so it's simply $\$10$ a percent, and we must spend anywhere between $\$200$ and $\$750$ per trial.

Comment: What makes a percent be efficient? As you state it, the success rate increases until you invest $550$, at which point you have hit the cap of $75\%$

Comment: @BrianTung maximum probability of success with the $2500
Edit: Now that I think about it, all the percents have the same efficiency with $2500 or any amount of money

Comment: @RossMillikan I have no idea how you got 550 because if it's 200 for 20% then it's 750 for 75% (55*10+200)

Edit: Now that I think about it, all the percents have the same efficiency with $2500 or any amount of money

Comment: I missed the base cost, so $750$ is right